# Unable to use my LCD display with a PIC16

Tags: embedded, pic, display, lcd

Thanks for stopping by.

I am trying to use my new Midas MC21605G12W LCD display, based on Hitachi HD44. I use a PIC16.

I followed the datasheet thoroughly but couldn't make anything react. The display keeps showing light squares without a blink. No topic on the site could help me further.

I interface via 8bit in parallel, so all my port C is wired to DB0-DB7.

If anyone could tell me anything I did wrong, it would be great.

Thanks in advance for your time :-)

Here is my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <pic16f18875.h>


    #define RS LATBbits.LATB5  //data or instruction(LOW))
    #define E LATBbits.LATB7  //chip enable

    int i;    //for counters of delays

    /******************************MAIN************************************************/      

    void main()
        {
        TRISC = 0x00;     //défine in/outs
        TRISB = 0x00;     //Port B is for commands, port C is 
                          //for 8bit data and instructions
        ANSELC = 0x00;
        ANSELB = 0x00;          
        LATC = 0x00;
        LATB = 0x00;

    RS=0;                      //we start with instructions
        E=0;                        //enable is initiated at zero

    LATC=0b00111100;            //select function
            for (i=0;i<15;i++){}        //setting of the port (delay)
        E=1;                        //enable pulse 
            for (i=0;i<1;i++){}         //ensure it is read
        E=0;
            for (i=0;i<12000;i++){}     //lcd internal operations

    LATC=0b00001111;            //display on
            for (i=0;i<15;i++){}
        E=1;
            for (i=0;i<1;i++){}
        E=0;
            for (i=0;i<12000;i++){}

    LATC=0x01;                  //clear display
            for (i=0;i<15;i++){}
        E=1; 
            for (i=0;i<1;i++){}
        E=0; 
            for (i=0;i<12000;i++){} 

    LATC=0x07;                  //select position of cursor
            for (i=0;i<15;i++){}
        E=1; 
            for (i=0;i<1;i++){}
        E=0;
            for (i=0;i<12000;i++){}

    RS=1;                       //now we will send data

    LATC=0x41;                  //display "A" (ascii)
            for (i=0;i<15;i++){}
        E=1;
            for (i=0;i<1;i++){}
        E=0;
            for (i=0;i<12000;i++){}

    RS=0;

        while(1)
        {}
    }
```

Comment: It is not clear from your crude bit-bang timing that you are meeting the constraints of the part.  For example the minimum E pulse width is 450ns - are you certain that a loop count of 1 will achieve that?  Since `i` is not declared volatile, the compiler may even optimise out all of those timing loops in any case.  It would be far better to poll a hardware timer/counter for deterministic timing.  Either way you should ideally verify your timing and integrity with a scope or logic analyser.

Comment: Make life easier for yourself - write a delay function, a toggle E function etc., so you only need get those things right once and do not have to fix many lines of code to correct errors.

Comment: Where/how are you controlling the R/!W line?  You should poll the device for the busy flag clear before sending each instruction - for that you need to read as well as write.

Comment: Hey! Thats right I should definitely use "real" timers, I will change that. As well, I hadn't seen about any minimum E pulse width, and certainly my loop of 1 doesn't do the trick.

Comment: My RW is bridged to the ground as I didn't want to complicate things. This is why I put a long loop after sending, to allow the internal operatin. But I should change that as well.

So, these are good hints, I will adapt all that :-)
Thanks a lot !

Comment: @bashal : All digital electronic devices have timing constraints - in this case see page 49 and Figure 25 (p.58) of the datasheet https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/LCD/HD44780.pdf for example.

Comment: Note also the tcycE is a _minimum_ - only the busy-flag polling is that quick.  Instruction execution time (busy time) is variable depending on the instruction as indicated in Table 6 (p.24).  If you are not checking the busy-flag, you must wait at least as long as the time indicated in table 6.

Comment: Ok I will look a little closer to that. I will come back to tell what I have achieved as soon as I will have had time to work on it !
Thank you so much @clifford, see you :)